# define an enum object in javascript and get string from it's key

Tags: javascript, enums

I have an object declared like this:

```
const State = {
    NoState = 0,
    FirstState = 1,
    SecondState = 2,
    ...
};
```

This State object defines a one directional forward FSM with numbers to indicate what state goes next.

Is there a way to print the name itself from the value of the state? I mean that this log:

```
console.log(State.FirstState);
```

will print 'FirstState' string to the console somehow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well then make it a string, not a number. Or make it some data structure that contains both a string and a number.

Comment: That's not how you declare an object. And why are you setting `1` as a value if you expect it to be a string `FirstState`?

Comment: But I need each value to be connected to the number to check that I am not going back inside my FSM.

Comment: That's invalid syntax for declaring an object

Comment: But is there a nice way to solve my problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check how Typescript enum are converted into javascript.

Your enum in Typescript :

```
enum State {
    NoState = 0,
    FirstState = 1,
    SecondState = 2,
};
```

Your enum converted in JS :

```
var State;
(function (State) {
    State[State["NoState"] = 0] = "NoState";
    State[State["FirstState"] = 1] = "FirstState";
    State[State["SecondState"] = 2] = "SecondState";
})(State || (State = {}));
```

It can seems a bit... hard but with that you are able to have both, int and string :

```
State.FirstState // 1
State[State.FirstState] // "FirstState"
```